# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Não' to data type tinyint

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel

I am trying to solve an error ,I created a variable to b store data that is in an Excel sheet. The error occurs when I try to insert the data that in SQL Server, in the query. Thanks for the help .

Code: variable declaration:

```
  String valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal = "";
```

Information search code:

```
 Case 47: // column 21

 If ((WS.Cells [row, Collation] as Excel.Range) .Value)! = Null)
{

Valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal = Convert.ToString ((WS.Cells [row, Contcoluna] as Excel.Range) .Value);

}
continue;
```

Insert code in sql server:

```
 }

break;
}

 If (WS! = Null)
  {
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ();
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT tabela_sacc (Grupo,Tipo_de_Instalacao,SubGrupo,Nr_Cliente,Data_Entidade,Situacao_da_entidade,Tipo_Entidade,Nome,Contribuinte,Tipo_Documento,Numero_Documento,Nr_Ident,Cod_Cliente_Sistema_Antigo,Entidade_Pagadora,Nome_Entidade_Pagadora,Numero_Contrato,Data_Contrato,Tipo_Contrato,Tipo_Sensibilidade,Tipo_de_Fatura,Nivel_de_Contador,Morada_de_Envio,Localizacao,Tipo_de_Medicao_Telemetria,Data_Vigencia,Ultimo_Dia_Estimado,Ultimo_Dia_Real,Ultimo_Dia_Faturado,Data_Ultima_Fatura,Data_Proxima_Fatura,Data_Situacao,Consumo_Medio_Real,Estimativa,Grupo_Contador,N_Contador,N_Referencia_Contador,Selos_do_Contador,Data_Instalacao,Leit_Cont_Simples_a_Data_Inst,Leit_Cont_Secundaria_a_Data_Inst,Leit_Cont_Principal_a_Data_Inst,Numero_Fabricante,Fabricante,Modelo_do_Contador,Calibre,Morada_Fiscal_Igual_a_Morada_Local,N_Rua_A,Rua_A,Policia_A,Andar_A,Localidade_A,Freguesia_A,Cod_Postal_A,Des_Postal_A,Zona_Postal_A,N_Rua_C,Rua_C,Policia_C,Andar_C,Localidade_C,Freguesia_C,Cod_Postal_C,Des_Postal_C,Zona_Postal_C,Nome_Fatura,N_da_Instalacao,N_Predio,Ramal,Ramal_Associado,Ramal_Saneamento,Anotacoes,Anotacoes_Ramal_Saneamento,Zona_Abastecimento,ZMC,Classe_Consumo,Tipo_Consumo,Grupo_Tarifario,Situacao,Zona,Area,Local,Local_em_Vigor,Tipo_Abastecimento,Caracteristica_Local,Calibre_Local,Local_Totalizador) VALUES ('" + valgrupo + "','" + valsubgrupo + "' ,'" + valtpinstalacao.ToString() + "','" + valnrcliente + "','" + valdataentidade.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valsituacaoentidade + "','" + valtpentidade + "','" + valnome + "','" + valcontrbuinte + "','" + valtpdoc + "','" + valndoc + "','" + valnridentidade + "','" + valcodclisistemaantigo + "','" + valentidadepagadora + "','" + valnomeentidadepagadora + "','" + valncontrato + "','" + valdatacontrato.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valtpcontrato + "','" + valtpsensibilidade + "','" + valtpfatura + "','" + valnivelcontador + "','" + valmoradaenvio + "','" + vallocalizacao + "','" + valtpmedicaotelemetria + "','" + valdatavigencia.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valultimodiaestimado.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valultimodiareal.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valultimodiafaturado.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valdataultimafatura.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valdataproximafatura.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valdatasituacao.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valconsumomedioreal + "','" + valestimativa + "','" + valgrupocontador + "','" + valncontador + "','" + valnreferenciacontador + "','" + valselocontador + "','" + valdatainstalacao.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + valleiturasimplescontadoradatainst + "','" + valleituraprincipalcontadoradatainst + "','" + valleiturasecundariacontadoradatainst + "','" + valnrfabricante + "','" + valfabricante + "','" + valmodelocontador + "','" + valcalibre + "','" + valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal.ToString() + "','" + valnruaa + "','" + valruaa + "','" + valpoliciaa + "','" + valandara + "','" + vallocalidadea + "','" + valfreguesiaa + "','" + valcodposltala + "','" + valdespostala + "','" + valzonapostala + "','" + valnruac + "','" + valruac + "','" + valpoliciac + "','" + valandarc + "','" + vallocalidadec + "','" + valfreguesiac + "','" + valcodpostalc + "','" + valdespostalc + "','" + valzonapostalc + "','" + valnomefatura + "','" + valninstalacao + "','" + valnpredio + "','" + valramal + "','" + valramalassociado + "','" + valramalsaneamento + "','" + valanotacoes + "','" + valanotacoesramalsaneamento + "','" + valzonaabastecimento + "','" + valzmc + "','" + valclasseconsumo + "','" + valtipoconsumo + "','" + valgrupotarifario + "','" + valsituacao + "','" + valzona + "','" + valarea + "','" + vallocal + "','" + vallocalemvigor + "','" + valtpabastecimento + "','" + valcaracteristicalocal + "','" + valcalibrelocal + "','" + vallocaltotalizador + "')";
  Connection.Open();
  Cmd.Connection = connection;
  Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  Connection.Close();
  valmoradafiscaligualmaradalocal= null;


  break;
  }

  }
  MessageBox.Show ("end");
  }


  }
```

Comment: Before you anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ Your code is wide open to sql injection. You also should start wrapping your connection and command objects with a USING statement.

Comment: You could be more specific so i can correct myself

Comment: The link I provided explains how to prevent sql injection by using parameters. You can look at their examples. And even half hearted attempt to search for USING would land you here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: You also seem to have normalization issues in your table. It appears you have repeating groups as indicated by Rua_A, Rua_C etc. These types of things will come back to bite you. They should be a separate table instead of sets of columns. Consider how painful it will be if you need to add another set. You will have to modify the table and update every single query that touches the table. If instead they were rows your whole system would just work.

Comment: I know this was a requested job, and this is the first step to insert the data all into one table and then yes into separate tables

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check the column in SQL, because seems like the 'morada_Fiscal_Igual_a_Morada_Local' column is a tinyint type and not a text to get the string "Não"

If you are trying to make a boolean type, use the type "bit"

For now, you can make this:

```
"VALUES ('" + valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal.ToString() == "Não" ? "0" : "1" + "')"
```

PS: Na proxima vez preste atenção, se o campo for um tinyint, ou bit, quer dizer que ele quer receber 0 ou 1, assim como em um campo de verdadeiro ou falso.

Comment: Thank you, but the data type of the column is varchar (50), so what is your suggestion?

Comment: Now that i notice, aren't you missing the "into" in the insert query? "Insert into table_sacc" ?

Comment: I tried, but that's not the problem! so what can i do now? 
I'm not showing the whole code, because the query is huge.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, I don't know if this is the entire insert, but the only thing that I cant think, is that you are missing the order of the (Columns) X (Values). Maybe it has a mixed order that cause this issue. This is the last thing that I can think.

Comment: I did not know that this would affect, in that case it is very possible, thank you.
But even if this is the problem when I do a single query it should not give error

Comment: If I do only one query will insert into the sql the front column. 
This may help